# Using Restassured how can i select a body as form-type format add Key value pair

Tags: rest-assured

I am new to Rest-assured. How can i add Body as data-form and Update the Key and Value pair.

public class RestAssuredRequests {

```
private static String requestBody = "{\n" +
        "  \"login\": \"login\",\n" +
        "  \"email\": \"TEST\",\n" +
        "  \"pass\": \"ATEST\" \n}";

@BeforeMethod
public static void setup() {
    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://TEST/login";
}

@Test
public void postRequest() {
    Response response = given()
            .body(requestBody)
            .when()
            .post()
            .then()
            .extract().response();
    System.out.println(response);

    //assertEquals(201, response.statusCode());
    //assertEquals("foo", response.jsonPath().getString("title"));
    //assertEquals("bar", response.jsonPath().getString("body"));
    //assertEquals("1", response.jsonPath().getString("userId"));
    //assertEquals("101", response.jsonPath().getString("id"));
}
```

}

Comment: NOTE: header("Content-type", "multipart/form-data")  is not working

Answer (score 0):

You could use `multipart` method

```
given().log().all()
        .multiPart("login", "login")
        .multiPart("email", "TEST")
        .multiPart("pass", "ATEST")
        .post("https://postman-echo.com/post").prettyPrint();
```

This is the response

```
"form": {
        "login": "login",
        "email": "TEST",
        "pass": "ATEST"
}
```